# Controller's properties does not change dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
   .controller('ImageChangeController', function($scope, $http, $element){
        $scope.itemid = '';

        reader = new FileReader();
        file_inputs = $element.children('.img-change');
        img_doc = $element.children('img').get(0);

        file_inputs.change(function(e){
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                img_doc.src = e.target.result;
            }
            $scope.itemid = "999"; //does not work

        });

      $scope.change_name = function(){
         $scope.itemid = "999";
      }
```

here is my template code:

```
    <div  ng-controller="ImageChangeController">
    <span>{{itemid}}</span>
    <input type="file" class="img-change" name="{{itemid}}"  accept="image/*">
    </div>
```

if I change `itemid` through `ng-click="change_itemid()"`, it will be work well.

Comment: use a angular directive instead of using Jquery : http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should use angular directives instead of non-native elements:
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload

If you want to solve problem without changing the implementation (for example, the direcitve does not give you feature you want):

The problem source is this part of code:

```
    file_inputs.change(function(e){
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            img_doc.src = e.target.result;
        }
        $scope.itemid = "999"; //does not work

    });
```

the function is called outside the angular digest cycle. You should inform angular about changes:

```
    file_inputs.change(function(e){
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            img_doc.src = e.target.result;
            $scope.$applyAsync();
        }
        $scope.itemid = "999"; //does not work
        $scope.$applyAsync();
    });
```

Comment: And I through ng-change to capture the modify, : ).